# How to show (multiple) params from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, helper

I have a webshop with an admin user indexpage to check user information. On this page I now want to show the shipping address (with firstname, lastname, street...).

I've managed to create this helper method to get the firstname, by using the user_id, which both the user and shipping_address have:

```
module Admin::CustomersHelper
 def customer(user)
  s = ShippingAddress.find_by(id: user)
  if s
   s.firstname
  end
 end
end
```

In my views I have:

```
<%= customer(@user.id) %>
```

This works, but the problem is that I need to show 10+ different params, and there's got to be a better way than making 10 different helper methods...

I've also tried to do <%= customer(@user.id).firstname %>, but this gives the error *undefined method `firstname' for nil:NilClass*.

---

My Admin::CustomersController:

```
def index
 @users = User.all
 @shipping_addresses = ShippingAddress.all
end
```

Some relevant parts of my schema.rb:

```
create_table "shipping_addresses", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "firstname"
 t.string "lastname"
 t.string "street"
 ...etc
 t.bigint "user_id"
 t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_shipping_addresses_on_user_id"
 ..etc
 add_foreign_key "invoice_addresses", "users"
 add_foreign_key "order_items", "orders"
 add_foreign_key "order_items", "products"
 add_foreign_key "orders", "order_statuses"
 add_foreign_key "orders", "users"
 add_foreign_key "shipping_addresses", "users"
end
```

Comment: Use associations, @user.shipping_address.attribute

Comment: `@user.shipping_address` will only work if the association is defined.

Comment: No need to prepend text "SOLVED" to question title. SO detects the answered questions itself. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say your code works for displaying one field of customer, but i doubt that.

Your code here is very confusing:

```
module Admin::CustomersHelper
  def customer(user)
    s = ShippingAddress.find_by(id: user)
    if s
      s.firstname
    end
  end
end
```

Few points:

1. Method name suggests that it returns an instance of `Customer` or similar model. But It is returning a string OR nil (in cases).
2. Method accepts an argument under name *user*, which one would assume to be an instance of `User` class. But actually it is an ID.
3. You are querying on `id` field. I think it should be on `user_id`.
4. I would not return a particular field from the method, but the instance of `ShippingAddress`. So that, i don't have to call multiple methods to display multiple fields.

So, the updated code would be like this:

```
module Admin::CustomersHelper
  def shipping_address_for(user_id)
    ShippingAddress.find_by(user_id: user_id)
  end
end
```

And in views,

```
<% shipping_address = shipping_address_for(@user) %>
<% if shipping_address %>
  <%= shipping_address.firstname %>
  <%= shipping_address.lastname %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Great points on the helper method. I know it was a mess, I'm new to Rails and correctly naming things is definitely something I need to work on. 

You were correct by the way. By coincidence there was a shipping address with the same id as the user_id, but the two didnt belong to the same user...